# Error while archiving the artifacts for a Jenkins freestyle project?

Tags: jenkins, pom.xml, artifacts, archiving, jenkins-build-flow

can someone help me to understand why I am supposed to add **POM.XML** file when I am trying to archive the artifacts in a Jenkins freestyle project? let me know if I'm missing something or if my understanding is wrong.

Is this only way to approach to archive the artifacts for a freestyle project. If Yes, please explain why? If no, please guide me through the alternate process.

for an additional and clear picture of what I am talking about referring to the screenshot provided below:

[image]

NOTE: Error screenshot informing me that **POM.XML** file is missing

Comment: are you sure it is failing in archiving ? because from the logs it seems that `mvn package` is failing which is maven package build step

Comment: I believe the reason why the mvn package is failing to compile, is because it is unable to find the pom.xml reference in the build information. I know that for sure because, I haven't added the links to that file in that build. 

And why I did not: because this is a freestyle project...

All I want to know is : is it mandatory to add a pom.xml file while building a free style java project.

Comment: yes it is mandatory to provide pom.xml while building a project.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Appreciate it.